# Build failed ionic project execution failed for task : processDebugResources'

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I used to build and run my project with no problems. But, now I have this error eevry time I run `ionic run android`:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.E
xecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\hamiri\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-
tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.
```

My Android SDK is updated, and so is ionic. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Set environment variable like this in Environment variable
ANDROID_HOME=  E:\sdk
JAVA_HOME=  C:\Program Files\Java\ jdk
PATH = %PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\build-tools\23.0.1;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;C:\Users\userXYZ\AppData\Roaming\npm

Comment: Android_home: E:\ what is E?

Comment: Its a basically SDK loction i have put my sdk in E drive